# NextsJS/React integration with Google Places API

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, next.js, google-places-api

I'm creating a project using Firebase and need to create an input field where the user can type a name/adress(and the interface shows some results) or use their own location(lat, lng) to find suggestions nearby.

My application has very specific behavior, so I'm not interested in autocomplete or other solutions, I only need an API that gives me a list of possible results.

The examples shown in the documentation don't fit with React nor NextJS very well, so I'm confused.

Looking at Google's official documentation([text](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/overview)) it seemed quite straight forward to use the Place search API.

I checked and tested many permissions configurations, nothing worked.

When trying to use the URL version of the API I have CORS error of type:
`Access to fetch at 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?key=API_KEY&input=string&inputtype=textquery' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

Also, the documentation leans towards inserting scripts and calling them in a Javascript fashion, but I'm implementing my logic with useEffects and memoized functions and it's not clear how to integrate it. **I only want a simple API call that gives me the array of results.**

I have two doubts:

1. How to solve the CORS problem given that I don't have access to Google's backend, do not plan to implement my own proxy server and already tried to add no-cors to the request ?
2. Even with CORS solved, will I have to use another API like Mapbox to solve my problem or is Google's Web Service API reliable to be called from the client side ?

Examples are very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

- Write a Firebase function (or alternative of your choice) that executes the API request server to server.
- Find a way to use the JavaScript library.

The web service is not intended to work if it gets called from a frontend, that is working as intended.

Comment: The Cloud Function seems to be working perfectly, thank you.